# Big size array while marshalling

Tags: c#, marshalling

i use a c function in a (.dll) file that takes a reference to array of struct and returns a byte that determines whether my operation is succeed or not.
it works well in the c project 
and worked well when i send a small size array(up to 7 elements)
and false after that !!

the array is from the following struct

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MainStruct
    {
        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.Struct, SizeConst = 5)]
        public Struct2 Struct2Object;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]
        public UInt64 Elem1;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]
        public UInt64 Elem2;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]
        public UInt64 Elem3;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]
        public UInt64 Elem4;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]
        public UInt64 Elem5;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]
        public UInt64 Elem6;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]
        public UInt64 Elem7;

        [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]
        public UInt64 Elem8;

    };
```

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. How does the native definition of the function looks like? How did you define it in C#? Can you debug the native function to see why it return false?

Comment: Also, if you want to have a `struct` that is marshaled with an embedded array, you can use `UnamanagedType.ByValArray` on an array, instead of several fields. Another question: how does the native function find out how big the array is?

Comment: You are going to have to stop lying with SizeConst.  There's no scenario I can think of where a UInt64 can have only 1 byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    __declspec(dllexport) TU08 GetBuffer(MainStruct *OBJ)
    {
    TU64 SelectedOBIS;
    TU08 XdrBuffer[Dlms_mXdrMaxBuffer];
    TU08 *pXdrBuffer;
    TU32 i;
    TU32 NumberOfElements;

    pXdrBuffer = XdrBuffer;
    SelectedOBIS = ProfilesData[LOG_ID_1].ProfilesOBISCodes;

        pXdrBuffer = XdrBuffer;
        Dlms_gXdrInitBuffer();
        /////// Get Data ///////
        if(Main_iSendGetRequest(SelectedOBIS, 7, 2, XdrBuffer) == false)
            return 0;
        /////// Extract Data ///////
        if(*XdrBuffer == Dlms_mXdrArray)
        {
            NumberOfElements = *(pXdrBuffer + 1);
            pXdrBuffer += 2; // 2 for array tag and its number of fields 
            for(i=0; i<NumberOfElements; i++)
            {
                if(*pXdrBuffer == Dlms_mXdrStruct)
                {
    pXdrBuffer += 2; // 2 for struct tag and its number of fields 
    pXdrBuffer = gGetDateTime(pXdrBuffer, &OBJ[i].TimeStamp);
    pXdrBuffer = gGetLongUnsigned(pXdrBuffer, &OBJ[i].StatusRegister);
    pXdrBuffer = gGetUnsigned(pXdrBuffer, &OBJ[i].EventCode);
    }
            }
        }
    return 1;
}
```

that`s the used function.

and this is the struct in C

```
typedef struct
{
    Struct2 Struct2OBject;
    TU64 Elem1;
    TU64 Elem2;
    TU64 Elem3;
    TU64 Elem4;
    TU64 Elem5;
    TU64 Elem6;
    TU64 Elem7;
    TU64 Elem8;
} MainStruct;
```

the marshal of the function is

```
    [DllImport("dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern byte GetBuffer([In, Out] MainStruct[] Profile);
```

the point is that it works well in C and works well in the windows form application too if the size of the array passed to the function is 7 or less !

Comment: Lose the `[MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.U8, SizeConst = 1)]`. It is wrong given the native definition. Can't see anything else wrong, *perse*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have hard-coded 8 bytes in your struct. Of course, you will get memory corruption if you go over that limit.

If there is a potentially unlimited amount of bytes to be "sent" I'd allocate an unamanaged buffer using Marshal.AllocHGlobal and pass it to the unmanaged function.

Comment: i`ve tried what u said ..
MainStruct OBJ = (MainStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointertostruct, typeof(MainStruct));
the pointer conatins data but it just initializes the object with zeros !!

Comment: You understand that you haven't given enough information to help you?

Comment: i do :(
the struct previously displayed ..
the prob. now is that i have a pointer to the data and can`t convert it to the struct

Answer (score 0):

i`ve tried to use pointer to get the data in :( .. 
and till this point it works ok.

```
MainStruct OBJ = (MainStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pointertostruct, typeof(MainStruct));
```

the pointer gets the data but it just initializes the object with zeros !!